# NSPredicate in Realm that filters on the current time

Tags: ios, date, realm, nspredicate

I am trying to create a NSPredicate (for use in Realm with Collection notifications) that filters records based on the current time.

NOT the time when the predicate was created:

```
NSPredicate(format: "endsAt < %@", NSDate())
```

But the time when the predicate is evaluated is something like this:

```
NSPredicate(format: "endsAt < now()")
```

because dynamic values and block based predicates isn't allowed is there an alternative solution ?

Comment: I don't use Swift, but I guess that you can filter with defined dates, no? So what about creating a var that has the current date, send use that var into the predicate? For instance, how do you filter a date that "startsAt yesterday midday"?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible as the values substituted into a predicate are fixed when the predicate is created. Please file an [enhancement request against Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/new) so we can track adding support for this sort of query in the future.